# Casting at runtime, .net6 or 2023 edition

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

```
public static void PublicConfigure(this WebApplicationBuilder builder)
{
    PrivateConfigure(builder);
}
        
public static void PublicConfigure(this IWebHostBuilder builder)
{
    PrivateConfigure(builder);
}

public static void PublicConfigure(this IHostBuilder builder)
{
    PrivateConfigure(builder);
}

private static void PrivateConfigure(object builder)
{
    var _builder = builder as (builder.GetType())
    if (_builder is WebApplicationBuilder)
    {
        //work with the _builder 
    }
    else
    {
        //work with the _builder 
    } 
}
```

I know this won't compile as is, however you get the idea and is there any way to handle this? Note that, if I only work with "if" statement without casting it, then it won't recognize the object and won't give me its members.

Comment: _"however you get the idea"_ - TBH I - don't. Since you perform type check, why do you need the "cast"?

Comment: "Note that, if I only work with "if" statement without casting it, then it won't recognize the object and won't give me its members."

Comment: Then use it only inside the `if`. Those types do not have common base type (besides `object`) so there is not much sense in introducing  `PrivateConfigure`, if you want DRY - then move the common parts into methods like `ConfigureConfig(ConfigurationManager )` and then call it in each of the methods (`ConfigureConfig(WebApplicationBuilder.Configuration)`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those types do not have common base type (besides `object`) so I would argue there is not much sense in introducing `PrivateConfigure` in the first place, if you want DRY - then move the common parts into separate private methods and then call them in each of the public ones. Something like:

```cs
public static void PublicConfigure(this WebApplicationBuilder builder)
{
     PrivateConfigureServices(builder.Services);
}
        
public static void PublicConfigure(this IWebHostBuilder builder)
{
    builder.ConfigureServices(PrivateConfigureServices)
}

public static void PublicConfigure(this IHostBuilder builder)
{
    builder.ConfigureServices(PrivateConfigureServices)
}

private static void PrivateConfigureServices(IServiceCollection sc)
{
    // ...
}
```

Otherwise use pattern matching, though again IMO it beats the purpose of the method introduction:

```cs
private static void PrivateConfigure(object builder)
{
    if (builder is WebApplicationBuilder webApp)
    {
        // webApp
    }
    else if(builder is IWebHostBuilder whb)
    {
        // whb
    }
    else if(builder is IHostBuilder hb)
    {
        // use hb
    }
}
```

**UPD**

> I want to avoid having to use the same code for `WebHostBuilder` and `HostBuilder` as they share the same members

Again - they still are different types (check it yourself - [`IWebHostBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iwebhostbuilder?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and [`IHostBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0), and implementations also). C# is strongly typed and statically typed language (in most cases) so those types having similar members changes nothing. You can use [`dynamic`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/advanced-topics/interop/using-type-dynamic) but you really-really should not.

```cs
static void PrivateConfigure(object builder)
{
    if (builder is WebApplicationBuilder webApp)
    {
        //work with the _builder 
    }
    else
    {
        dynamic dynamicBuilder = builder;
        // will fail at runtime if no such method on type
        // no IntelliSense also
        dynamicBuilder.CallAnyMethodAtYourOwnRisk(); 
    } 
}
```

**Read also**:

- [C# type system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/)

Comment: I want to avoid having to use the same code for WebHostBuilder and HostBuilder as they share the same members opposite to WebApplicationBuilder, therefore I need to cast it (I guess)

Comment: @maxhustle you can't cast them, because there is nothing to cast to. They both inherit `object` and that's it. C# is strongly typed and statically typed language (in most cases), so classes having the same members are will not help here. You can use `dynamic` but I would hardly discourage that.

Comment: @maxhustle also how much extra work it would be to follow the suggested approach? Like 5-6 extra lines, maybe 10-12 (you actually can save some due to the code reusage for `WebApplicationBuilder` case)? There is not that much members exposed by those interfaces.

Comment: yeah I know that approach I hoped that will all the changes in .net there might be some solution to handle this case

Answer (score 2):

Why not just do the typecheck in the `if` and then, once you know what type it really is, cast it accordingly?

```
private static void PrivateConfigure(object builder)
{
    if (builder is WebApplicationBuilder)
    {
        var wab = builder as WebApplicationBuilder;
        wab.doSomething();
    }
    else if (_builder is ...)
    {
        var b = builder as ...
        b.doSomethingElse();
    } 
}
```

Comment: you can do that even shorter without an additional cast: `if (_builder is WebApplicationBuilder wap) { wap.doSomething(); }` That type matching pattern even works if you inline it ` _builder is WebApplicationBuilder wap ? wap.doSomething() : throw new Exception();`

Comment: @Marco Yeah, I'm not really always up to date with changes to the language specification. And I only tried this at dotnetfiddle (with compiler set to .net 7) and it threw an compilation error without the cast, so I included that here

Comment: I want to avoid having to use the same code for WebHostBuilder and HostBuilder as they share the same members opposite to WebApplicationBuilder, therefore I need to cast it (I guess)

Comment: @maxhustle I will repeat again - there is noting to cast to, except for `object`.

Comment: @derpirscher I've missed out on the new pattern matching and expression features for far too long, too, then I got a hold of it and by now, my code is starting to look a bit too arcane from time to time, so I reign it back in. Readability and stuff :/